# Relation between initial mass and evolutionary phases lifetimes

Tags: stellar-evolution, main-sequence, red-giant, initial-mass-function

Consider the following image (Source: An Introduction to Modern Astrophysics):
[image]

There seems to be a relation between the initial mass/mass at the beginning of the MS and the time spent during different evolutionary phases.

Is the this relation empirical or can it be quantified?

For example, the MS lifetime is proportional to $M / L$ , I want to know whether a relationship like this exists for other phases.

Edit 1:

See this image for more details, does there exist any quantitative relation from which these values can be obtained?

[image]

Comment: Yes, you can even find the relation on wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_sequence

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape Yes, I have mentioned that as an example in my question. I was actually wondering whether such relations existed for other evolutionary phases.

Comment: You should ask that in your question then. As it stands, you're asking about the MS.

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape I guess there is a misunderstanding. I have clearly written it as an example, I wanted to know whether a relationship like that existed for other phases. Nevertheless, I'll edit the question.